# Android 4.0 calendar api

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have a problem with listing all events in Google Calendar on Android OS.
I used [this tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/programming-with-the-Android-40-calendar-api-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/825)

But each time I have only 98 events (I have a lot more).

Each event is from January to March 2012 (I have events from 2011).

Here is my Code:

```
{
  private static final String LOG = "service";
  private Cursor mCursor = null;
  private static final String[] COLS = new String[]
{ CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION};
  Uri uri=CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;
  mCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, COLS, null, null, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART +" ASC");
  Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
  Log.i(LOG,mCursor.getCount()+"");
  while(mCursor.moveToNext()){
    date.setTimeInMillis(mCursor.getLong(1));   
    Log.i(LOG,mCursor.getString(0)+" "+date.get(Calendar.DATE)+"-"+date.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"-  "+date.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" "+date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+" "+date.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
  }
  return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

I'am trying to use Android 4.0 API to calendar. Can anyone help me with getting ALL the events from calendar? Any tutorials or something?

Comment: What calendar account are you reading events from? Your *own* (via a `SyncAdapter` etc) or a 3rd party source such Google Calendar or Exchange?

Comment: I intended to read Google Calendar.
This is all code i use for reading data from calendar.

Comment: Hm, have you gone back to 2011 in your Calendar application (on device) and attempted to view these events? Depending on the impl. a calendar sync application may omit to push events on the server that takes place in the past to client devices. Are you using a rooted device - in that case you can extract the SQLite file and check if it really has sync:ed down all the events you're expecting.